# How to run Angular 2 app on docker machine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, docker

I have deployed a simple `Angular 2` app which was created using `Angular CLI`. After building the `Docker` image I'm running it in a virtual box container.

The app is running in the container with the port exposed but, if I tried to access that `URL`, I'm getting an error saying the site can't be reached.

Below is my `Docker` file

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 5655
CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "baconv1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -H 0.0.0.0"
    ....
    ....
}
```

Even in package.json, I tried two different ways: setting `start` as `"ng serve"` and `"ng serve -H 0.0.0.0"`

I checked twice and the app is running properly in the container machine

Console

[image]

Kinematic
[image]

Even after exposing to default `Angular` port 4200 did not work!!!

[image]
Please help me by correcting, if needed, my existing config in Dockerfile or package.json

Comment: Have you tried port 4200? I think `ng serve` defaults to 4200 as a port. Update your expose to port 4200. You may also need to map that port when you start your container: `-p 5655:4200` (hostport:containerport). This will map the container port 4200 (what `ng serve` uses) to the host port of 5655 (where I am assuming you want your app running). Also - I think you should be doing a prod build of the application for speed using `ng build --prod` instead of running serve in a container.

Comment: ok let me try and update you

Comment: I have been in the same situation and according to Docker best practices (1 service per container) we have chosen 2 separate containers which shares a volume. Is there anything that stops you doing so too?

Comment: @Doug i tried exposing 4200 not worked 
 86a38112520c        baconv1:latest      "npm start"         56 seconds ago      Up 54 seconds       0.0.0.0:32773->4200/tcp   baconv1-2

Comment: @Sergiu dont try to run same image on multiple container ur memory will run out use docker stop <image name> to stop and run again if u made any changes